# Is smart contract receive, hold and send different kinds of ERC-20 tokens

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, metamask, erc20, ethers.js

I'm creating a smart contract using solidity and publishing it to the Mumbai Test Network.

Right now when I'm interacting with the contract on the client-side using ethers and metamask it's automatically using the MATIC token.

I want the smart contract to be able to receive different kinds of ERC-20 tokens and afterward be able to transfer them.

```
const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amount.toString(), 'ether');
const contract = await tokenContract.createTransfer({ value: parsedAmount });
```

For example, I want to be able to send the test token shown in the picture.

[Link to the faucet](https://faucet.polygon.technology/)

[image]

I've searched online and read docs but couldn't find an answer for this problem...

If needed, I will add any info you think will clarify this question!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ERC-20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) doesn't define any way to let the receiving contract know about a transfer that is not initiated by the receiver. It "only" emits an event but that's not readable from onchain.

All ERC-20 balances are stored in the respective token contracts. For example, if an address holds 10 USDC, this information is stored on the USDC contract - no matter if the holder is an end user address or a contract.

Combined these two things together, you can send a transaction to the USDC (or any other ERC-20) token contract, invoking the `transfer()` function where the receiver is your contract. This will effectively transfer USDC from the user to your contract address.

```
const usdcContract = new ethers.Contract(usdcAddress, usdcAbi, metamaskSigner);
const to = "0x123..."; // your contract address
const amount = "1000000"; // 1 token with six decimals
await usdcContract.transfer(to, amount);
```

Comment: Thanks! now I understand how the ERC-20 works.
To create the contract, I need the contract's ABI.
I've tried to find it on the Mumbai polygon scan but with no success- [link](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/token/0x2d7882bedcbfddce29ba99965dd3cdf7fcb10a1e?a=0x2d7882beDcbfDDce29Ba99965dd3cdF7fcB10A1e).
 Is there a way to fetch it only with the contract address?

Comment: @AlonBenYaakov If you're planning to use just the ERC20 functions and not any specific functionality of this particular contract, you can use a generic ERC20 ABI found anywhere online... But it's not technically possible to get an ABI from just the bytecode.

Comment: Excellent  I'm able to send different kinds of ERC20 tokens to the same contract address :)
If I want to send the same token back from the contract, what is the command I need to use in solidity?

Comment: @AlonBenYaakov Assuming your contract holds the token, you can invoke the token contract's function `transfer()` from your contract: `bool success = IERC20(tokenContractAddress).transfer(recipient, amount);`. Don't forget to import or define the IERC20 interface alongside your contract. Example: `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";`